Why am I getting no folders in by VSCode project and the selection in Explorer and View are greyed out?
enter image description here This image shows the exampe of greyed out and NO folders for my project. This is a recent problem, the folders were there last week and the problem is occuring in more than one of my projects.
I tried looking at the folders in the Explore tab and cannot make them active. I looked at the folders in the view dropdown and they did not take any effect.
